# How to get items break to next row if they exceeds to 3 columns with flexbox css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to loop an array of objects and display them in grid view but with the flexbox concept in CSS.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="innercontainer">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4 (to go to row 2 if there is 4)</div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

```
.container { 
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: red; 
}

.innercontainer {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

The above code works perfectly fine until 3 items. When 4th item comes, I want it to go to the next row.

I tried some research and did this but not working.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="innercontainer">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="breaker"></div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="breaker"></div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="breaker"></div>
    <div class="item">4 (to go to row 2 if there is 4)</div>
    <div class="breaker"></div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

I appended this css code to above css, but not working.

```
.breaker {
  display: none;
}
.breaker:nth-child(3n) {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}
```

You can see them in codepen. (https://codepen.io/apple-hhh/pen/bGMMByr)

What I want is:

[image]

With my first implementation, I have achieved the first 2 scenarios from the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS grid for this:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.container > div:nth-child(3n + 1) {grid-column: 1}
.container > div:nth-child(3n + 2) {grid-column: 2}
.container > div:nth-child(3n + 3) {grid-column: 3}


.container > div {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `flex-basis: 25%;` to your `.item` class. Usually, 33% would work but since you have padding in the item class, you might have to play around with it a bit.

flex-basis: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis

In my experience using `grid` instead of `flex` is better here.

Comment: Yes. The 4th item breaks down to the 2nd row, but its width is still 100%.

Answer (score -1):

.item{
background-color: yellow;

width: 33%;

flex-grow: 1;
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).